# Admob banner ad display height is not coming correctly in android game made with andengine

Tags: android, android-layout, admob, andengine

I have implemented admob | GoogleMobileAdSDK into my android game build with andengine. The ads are loading into the game but not displaying correctly for the first time after opening the app. But when I go out of app activity say by clicking an add or going to google play leaderboard and come back to the app then it starts displaying it correctly. 
So basically when I open the app the ads are coming with full width but almost with half height. And if clicked on the ad, goes to the ad link and come back to my app by pressing back button the ad comes with full width full height. Stuck on this for 3 days :/

```
public static AdView adView;
@Override
protected void onSetContentView() {

    final FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
    final FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameLayoutLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    adView = new AdView(this);
    new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId("MY AD UNIT ID");
    final FrameLayout.LayoutParams adViewLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    this.mRenderSurfaceView = new RenderSurfaceView(this);
    mRenderSurfaceView.setRenderer(this.mEngine, this);

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice("MY EMULATOR ID")
    .addTestDevice("MY DEVICE ID")
    .build();

    final FrameLayout.LayoutParams surfaceViewLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    frameLayout.addView(this.mRenderSurfaceView,surfaceViewLayoutParams);
    frameLayout.addView(adView,adViewLayoutParams);
    this.setContentView(frameLayout, frameLayoutLayoutParams);

    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    Log.d("Ads","AdView banner size is "+adView.getWidth()+" and "+adView.getHeight());
    //Creating the banner view.

}
```

Also the log i feed into the code to see adview sizes. it always print this on the starting of the app

> AdView banner size is 0 and 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the `adView` to the `frameLayout` only after it finishes loading:

```
adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    public void onAdLoaded(){
        frameLayout.addView(adView, adViewLayoutParams);
    }
});
```

If your ad is refreshing you may want to check first if the `adView` is already added to the `frameLayout` before adding it, or it will crash.

Comment: Thanks man. Been stuck on it for last 3-4 days. This solves the issue. :)
Can you tell a little bit more on refreshing? What do I have to do exactly if I want to refresh the ad?

Comment: My app is crashing as you mentioned and for the same region.What exactly do i have to do to stop this? Do I have to remove view and re-add it or can I use the previous framelayout itself?

Comment: Hi, glad I could help. You can use the previous frameLayout itself, just have to check if adView.getParent is null (which means that the adView hasn't been added to the frameLayout) before adding it, this way it will only add the adView once to the frameLayout. I don't know if that's the best solution out there but it works!

Comment: Cool. As of now I am just using setvisibility method as I think there is no need to remove view.